# Get value of selected option from dropdown list using kohana

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

How to get values from dropdown list when option is selected and trigger the submit button immediately. I can do it in `php` but i want to do it using `kohana` but no idea. I am new to it and using `kohana 3.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Kohana controller you would use the `request` object to access the POST data. For example:

```
$selectedValue = $this->request->post('dropdownlist');
```